# Save id of selected item from drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to save the id of selected item from drop down box?

For ex: From the drop down box I selected xbox where the id of xbox is 2. The id of xbox should be saved in database and show xbox in UI.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you've already tried? Cheers

Comment: Can you show your code and be more precise ?

Comment: i tried to alert the value, im getting the value in alert but im unable to save in db

Comment: And what do you use to save in DB? Please create give us more *context*

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple solution with jquery.

```js
function showProduct(str) {
 var text =$('#ddb option:selected').val();
    alert(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
<select id="ddb" onchange="showProduct(this.value)">
<option  value="">Select product:</option>
<option  value="1">XBOX</option>
<option value="2 ">PS4</option>
<option  value="3">PC</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
```

persisting value to db is another topic. you can give more information about which platform to persist data(hibernate,native jdbc,entity framework etc.).

Comment: As @ARA said in the comments, he can get the value of the element and `alert()` it, the problem lies on saving it to the database.